# PIC prints garbage character instead of intended character

Tags: c, bluetooth, printf, pic

I want to make a simple test with my PIC18F4550, bluetooth module HC-06 and the computer.
I mean, I want to sent a simple character from the PIC to the PC using the bluetooth module.

It was supposed to appear an "A" in the terminal but what appear is a F8 in HEX (ASCII:seems like a "o" with a slash inside). I've try instead a `printf`, a `puts` or a `fputs`, but F8 still appears plus this symbol "€".

My code and schematic is next...can somebody help me finding my mistake?

(I'm using RCom Serial or CoolTerminal)

```
#include <18f4550.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#fuses XT, NOWDT, NOPROTECT, PUT, BROWNOUT, NOLVP, NOCPD, NOWRT

#use delay (clock=4000000)

#use rs232(baud=9600, xmit=PIN_C6, rcv=PIN_C7, bits=8, parity=N)

void main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which type of code is this? What is `18f4550.h`, `#fuses`, `#use delay`, `#use rs232` ? It is not even compiling.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained, compilable example of what you're trying to achieve and what is your specific problem.

Comment: This may not solve your problem but you might want to consider flushing stdout following every printf call.

Comment: Suspect signal is inverted ( or maybe mis-matched baud).  `'A'` is 0b0100_0001  (5 `0` bits in a row).  0xF8 has 5 ones in a row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalized code to print debug messages on the UART port.
NOTE:

```
#include <xc.h>
// Use your uC header file
#include <pic16f877a.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#define FREQ _XTAL_FREQ
#define baud 9600
#define spbrg_value (((FREQ/64)/baud)-1)

unsigned char UARTdata;

void serial_init()
{
    SPBRG=spbrg_value;
    //SPBRG=31;
    //TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;
    //CSRC: Clock Source Select bit            0
    //TX9 : 9-bit Transmit Enable bit          0
    //TXEN: Transmit Enable                    0  
    //SYNC: EUSART Mode Select bit             0
    //SENDB: Send Break Character bit          0
    //BRGH: High Baud Rate Select bit          0
    //TRMT: Transmit Shift Register Status bit 1
    //TX9D: Ninth bit of Transmit Data         0
    TXSTA=0x20;

    //RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;
    //RCSTAbits.CREN = 1    
    //bit 7 SPEN: Serial Port Enable bit        1
    //bit 6 RX9: 9-bit Receive Enable bit       0
    //bit 5 SREN: Single Receive Enable bit     0
    //bit 4 CREN: Continuous Receive Enable bit 1
    //bit 3 ADDEN: Address Detect Enable bit    0
    //bit 2 FERR: Framing Error bit             0
    //bit 1 OERR: Overrun Error bit             0
    //bit 0 RX9D: 9th bit of Received Data      0
    RCSTA=0x90;
    //Setting 
    TRISCbits.TRISC6=0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC7=1;
}

void putch(unsigned char UARTdata)
{
    while( ! TXIF)
        continue;
    TXREG = UARTdata;
}



// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC  = HS      // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE  = OFF     // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF    // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON    // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP   = OFF      // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD   = OFF      // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT   = OFF      // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP    = OFF       // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)


void main()
{
  serial_init();

  printf("DRIVER Enjoy Direct print method!");

  while(1)
  {

    __delay_ms(1000);
    printf("A");
    __delay_ms(1000);     

  }                    
}
```